# Add custom CSS class to legend element of WFFM form section

Tags: sitecore, web-forms-for-marketers

I am looking to add a CSS class to the legend element associated with a Web Forms for Marketers form. In the Form Section item in Sitecore I can add `<ShowLegend>Yes</ShowLegend>` to the Parameters field, which does add a legend element with class `scfSectionLegend`. That's nice, but I want to add a custom class that hides the legend text. How do I do this?

**UPDATED:**

I was able to resolve this by adding some css onto the existing CSS class `scfSectionLegend`. I added this:

```
    /* ACCESSIBILITY: Legend text should be intact but hidden for screen readers */
    clip: rect(1px, 1px, 1px, 1px); 
    height: 1px; 
    width: 1px; 
    overflow: hidden; 
    position: absolute !important;
```

This works fine assuming we will never want WFFM legend text to be visible for this project, but that might change. I would like to be able to single out a specific occurrence in the DOM where the parent div has `hideClass` - something like this:

```
.hideClass.scfSectionBorderAsFieldSet.scfSectionLegend {
   [CSS properties here]
}
```

That way content authors control whether a legend is hidden or not. Unfortunately after running this, the CSS does not work; it does not hide the legend text. Thoughts? My CSS knowledge is not that great.

Comment: Wondering if it would be easy enough to just add global JS that looks for elements with the class `scfSectionLegend` and adds the class there? Since we don't really need any of the legends on the site to be visible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Answer from @Anton is pretty close, but I would suggest that you apply your CSS differently.

Add the parameters to match your CSS style: `<CssClass>hideLegend</CssClass>`

The CSS Class will be applied to the parent fieldset and the markup should be similar to:

```html
<fieldset class="hideLegend">
    <legend>Custom Fields</legend>
        ...
    </div>
</fieldset>
```

Then create a style to target the legend only if the parent fieldset has the required class:

```css
fieldset.hideLegend legend {
    /* your custom CSS here */
    left: -9999px;
    position: relative;
}
```

Depending on the version of WFFM, you may see the following field options wen you select a section:

[image: Section Appearance]

If so you can add custom CSS classes to the drop list by creating an item under `/sitecore/system/Modules/Web Forms for Marketers/Settings/Meta data/Css Classes` of template type `/sitecore/templates/Web Forms for Marketers/Meta Data/Extended List Item`. Set the item name to something friendly for your editors and `Value` field to match the CSS Class name (as above for example).

The above was checked on Sitecore 8.1 Update 3 and WFFM 8.1 160523, the markup and screens may vary on different versions.

Answer (score 1):

There is Parameters field in section item.
You can modify its value and set:

```
<CssClass>hideClass</CssClass><ShowLegend>Yes</ShowLegend>
```

[image]

Comment: Hmm.. I tried that and published the form section, cleared cache and reloaded, my legend markup still looks like this: `<legend class="scfSectionLegend">
    Simple types
   </legend>`, and the text "Simple types" is still visible. It looks like the div above the fieldset did get hideClass though: `<div class="hideClass">`.

Comment: @Paul: Why not make the class `hideLegend` and then use some CSS to hide the legend: `div.hideLegend legend { display: none }` ?

Comment: @jammykam I was thinking of something like that. I edited my question.

Comment: @jammykam It looks like your solution might work considering the edits I made to my question. Let me try that out and see if it works.

Comment: @jammykam Worked like a charm. If you post your comment as an answer I will accept. Thanks!